# Tensor product and fiber product of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

The tensor product of modules commutes with finite products, i.e. if $A,B,C$ are $R$-modules, then we have
$$A\otimes_R(B\times C)\cong (A\otimes_R B) \times (A\otimes_R C).$$
My question is whether this is true for more general fiber products, i.e. if we have
$$A\otimes_R(B\times_D C)\cong (A\otimes_R B) \times_{A\otimes_R D}  (A\otimes_R C)$$
where we recover the first case by setting $D=0$.

Comment: By fiber product do you mean, there are maps $f: B \to D$ and $g: C \to D$ and $B \times_D C = \{(b, c) \in B \times C : f(b) = g(c)\}$?

Comment: Yes I do. I suppressed the morphisms $f,g$ from the notation.

Comment: No, this is false in general for fiber products. the reason why tensor product commutes with Cartesian product is that the finite Cartesian product of modules coincides with the direct sum, and tensor product is a left adjoint.